# I want to disabled end time upto current time in datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datetimepicker

I want to disable end time upto current time in datetimepicker.

I am refer this link http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/.

In face of the issue, when I set mintime:0 at that time all date times get disabled.

[image: datetimepicker]

Answer (score 0):

Yo have to indicate date format attribute

```
jQuery.datetimepicker.setLocale('de');

jQuery('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
 i18n:{
  de:{
   months:[
    'Januar','Februar','März','April',
    'Mai','Juni','Juli','August',
    'September','Oktober','November','Dezember',
   ],
   dayOfWeek:[
    "So.", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", 
    "Do", "Fr", "Sa.",
   ]
  }
 },
 timepicker:false,
 format:'d.m.Y'
});
```